# No puedo importar módulo con python

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-import

Estoy teniendo un problema al tratar de importar un archivo .py que yo mismo creé.

Mi directorio es algo así:

```
---Headless
   --Pages
     -PassengerPage.py
     - __init__.py
   --Steps
     -ExecuteFlows.py
     - __init__.py
 - __init__.py
 - MainExecution.py
```

Yo realizo la importación del `ExecuteFlow.py` sin problemas desde el `MainExecution.py`, pero cuando quiero importarlo desde el `PassengerPage.py` me sale el error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ExecuteFlows' from 'Steps.ExecuteFlows' (C:\Users\usuario\PycharmProjects\Headless\Steps\ExecuteFlows.py)

Adjunto las imágenes que muestran el directorio, la importación y el error.

Error que se genera en PassengerPage.py:

> [image: Error que se genera en PassengerPage.py]

Comment: @eyllanesc Traté de hacer eso pero toma Steps como un paquete que tengo que instalar, así que no me funciona

Comment: @eyllanesc en la carpeta Headless ya creé un __init__.py y de hecho también el la carpeta Steps pero aún así no me funciona. (Se evidencia en la imagen), sigo aceptando ayuda, gracias

Comment: @FJSevilla no señor(a) , ejecuto MainExecution.py como módulo principal

Answer (score 0):

Buen día.
No es correcto importar un modulo como lo haces de acuerdo a la imagen.
Intenta con:

```py
from Steps import ExecuteFlows
```

Con esto indicamos que se traiga un modulo especifico de cierto paquete.
Y si deseas llamar una clase de `ExecuteFlows` podrías escribir:
`nomobjeto = ExecuteFlows.Clase()`
Tambien puedes intentar con:

```py
import Steps.Executeflow
```

Traerá el modulo directamente de acuerdo a la ruta.

**NOTA**: En *sublimeText* al ejecutar este llamado crea una carpeta llamada `__pycache__` la cual permite interpretar la carpeta como un paquete, si esta no existe no es posible realizar llamados como paquetes.